# How to prevent rotation of all UIImage overlays with MapKit

Tags: ios, rotation, uiimage, mapkit, mkoverlay

I am placing overlays with MapOverlayRenderer. I first use a UIImage in a view over the map and can rotate it in its view and then convert the points (define boundingMapRect, coordinate, etc.) and then place it (Renderer/addOverlay) onto the map with the correct inserted image (CGContextDrawImage) and correct rotation. Each time that I create a new overlay [UIImage in view, rotate, convert points, addOverlay) it works just fine. But, on each successive overlay added to the Map, the code also rotates all of the other overlays already on the map. It seems as though my rotation code (below) is being applied to all of the overlays.

Should I be making an array which includes boundingMapRect and coordinates for each overlay - if so, should these be in viewcontroller?
Should I be naming each overlay [overlay.title? - how do I set it and call it?]

Appreciate some guidance - thanks.

````
MapOverlayView.h
@interface MapOverlayView ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *overlayImage;
@end
@implementation MapOverlayView
- (instancetype)initWithOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay overlayImage:
(UIImage *)overlayImage {
self = [super initWithOverlay:overlay];
if (self) {
    _overlayImage = overlayImage;

    }
return self;

}
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:
(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    CGImageRef imageReference = self.overlayImage.CGImage;
    MKMapRect theMapRect = self.overlay.boundingMapRect;
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];
    IonQuestSingleton *tmp = [IonQuestSingleton sharedSingleton];
    float new_angle = tmp.image_angle;
    NSLog(@"%s%f","New angle is ",new_angle);

    {
    if (new_angle<90) {

            CGContextRotateCTM(context,new_angle*M_PI/180);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -theRect.size.height);
            CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
            NSLog(@"%s%f","New angle 90 is ",new_angle);//tick

        }
        else if (new_angle >90 && new_angle <=180)
        {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context,new_angle*M_PI/180);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, 0.0);
            CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
            NSLog(@"%s%f","New angle 180 is ",new_angle);//tick

        }
        else if (new_angle >180 && new_angle <=270)
        {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context,new_angle*M_PI/180);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -theRect.size.width, 0.0);
            CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);
            NSLog(@"%s%f","New angle 270 is ",new_angle);//tick

        }
        else if (new_angle >270) {
            CGContextRotateCTM(context,new_angle*M_PI/180);
            CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -theRect.size.width, 
-theRect.size.height);
            CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);//tick
            NSLog(@"%s%f","New angle 360 is ",new_angle);
    }
}
}
@end



MapOverlay.h
#import "MapOverlay.h"
#import "IonQuestSingleton.h"

@implementation MapOverlay
#define debug 1

@synthesize boundingMapRect;
@synthesize coordinate;

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
//Image center point
IonQuestSingleton *tmp = [IonQuestSingleton sharedSingleton];
return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tmp.image_ctr_lat,  
tmp.image_ctr_long);
}


- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    IonQuestSingleton *tmp = [IonQuestSingleton sharedSingleton];

    MKMapPoint upperLeft   =  
MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tmp.image_tl_lat,  
tmp.image_tl_long));

    MKMapPoint boundsLeft =  ```MKMapPointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(tmp.image_tl_bounds_lat,    tmp.image_tl_bounds_long));

boundingMapRect = MKMapRectMake(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y,  
fabs(upperLeft.x - boundsLeft.x), fabs(upperLeft.x - boundsLeft.x));
}

return self;
}
@end

Viewcontroller.h

-(void) loadOverlay
{
MapOverlay *overlay = [[MapOverlay alloc] init];
[self.mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
}

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:
(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {


NSString *mapNameFromMVCPos = [NSString  
stringWithFormat:@"%@%s",self.mapNameFromMVC,"Pos"];//not working

{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MapOverlay class]]) {

        UIImage *magicMountainImage = [UIImage 
imageNamed:mapNameFromMVCPos];

        MKOverlayRenderer *overlayView = [[MapOverlayView alloc] 
initWithOverlay:overlay overlayImage:magicMountainImage];

        return overlayView;
} etc [evaluate other overlaytypes]
````

Comment: I have added code to pull from Coredata the coordinates and boundingRect for appoints from either a single scaled & rotated UIImage (use a predicate) or for the complete set - in either case, all of the overlays are rotated by MapOverlayview.h, above.  However, the "current" UIImage whether being pulled from core data or directly written from calculated coordinates is always spot on. So, my question is - should the code ...if (new_angle >90 && new_angle <=180)... CGContextRotateCTM, CGContextScaleCTM, CGContextTranslateCTM, CGContextDrawImage ... be in the ViewController? Thx.